# How to pass data to table view controller being instantiated from UIStoryboard?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a ViewController with an UIScrollView which contains two TableViewControllers.

```
    let allViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ContentViewController") as! ContentViewController;
    let favoritesViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ContentViewController") as! ContentViewController;
```

At some point inside the scrollViewDidEndDecelerating delegate I want to send the current page from UIScrollView (1 or 2) to my ContentViewController:

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let page = Int(scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width)

    // how to send page to ContentViewController
    //delegate.pageChanged(page)
}
```

If I don't use prepareForSegue, how to actually send the data to may UITableViewController ?

What I tried is add a protocol to ViewController, but I can't initialize the delegate inside ContentVieController:

```
protocol PageChangedDelegate {
    func pageChanged(page: Int)
}

var delegate: PageChangedDelegate!

func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let page = Int(scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width)

    delegate.pageChanged(page) // delegate is nil here
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you instantiate a viewController and you are down casting use "as!" you now have access to the variables of that view controller,

lets assume your content view controller has variables A,B,C you can do it like this

```
let allViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ContentViewController") as! ContentViewController
allViewController.A = "Setting variable A on view controller"
allViewController.B = "hi"
allViewController.C = "the view controller now has its variables assigned"
```